# How to update a realtime matplotlib in tkinter without blocking the mainloop

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hi I have a realtime plot that is updating from a subscription using zmq. I'm using animate from matplotlib to reflect the latest update but I get a 1sec block each update. Is there a way to update the plot without getting blocked in the UI? You can "feel" the block if you drag the UI.py window around on the screen using your mouse.

publish data: (run this first: save this as Publisher.py and run it: python Publisher.py)

```
import zmq
from time import sleep
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)  # pylint: disable=no-member
socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:2020')

# noise
dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 30, dt)
nse1 = np.random.randn(len(t))
nse2 = np.random.randn(len(t))
nse3 = np.random.randn(len(t))

# sample data
s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t) + nse1
s2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t) + nse2
s3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t) + nse3

index = 0
while(True):
    sleep(0.10)
    messages = [{"p1":{"key1":"100.01"},
         "p2":{"key1":s1[index],"key2":s2[index],"key3":s3[index]},
         "p3":{"key1":"100100.45","key2":"200200.56"}}]
    print( 'index=',index," {",messages[0],"}" )
    socket.send_pyobj(messages[0])
    if( index == len(s1)-1 ):
        index = 0
    else:
        index = index + 1
```

UI (save this as UI.py and run it python UI.py)

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import time
import zmq
import threading as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
import numpy as np
from drawnow import *

key1=[]
key2=[]
key3=[]

PLOT_MAX=50
PLOT_FILL_COLOR='#8899b5ff'

class SIControllerUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("SIControllerUI-UI v2020")
        self.grid()

        self.subscribing = True
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.xit)

    def startup(self):
        self.create_widgets()
        self.tZmq = t.Thread(target=self.refreshState,args=[2020])
        self.tZmq.start()

    def isSubscribing(self):
        return self.subscribing

    def terminate(self):
        self.subscribing = False

    def xit(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            #self.terminate()
            '''while self.tZmq.is_alive()==True:
                print('Subscription still running. Waiting...')
                time.sleep(.5)
            self.tZmq.join()'''
            self.master.destroy()

    def create_widgets(self):
        None

    def refreshState(self,port):
        #print('getting message...')
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB) # pylint: disable=no-member
        subUrl = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:' + str(port)
        socket.connect(subUrl)
        try:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') # pylint: disable=no-member
        except TypeError:
            socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') # pylint: disable=no-member
        #print('refreshState isSubscribing='+str(self.isSubscribing()))
        while(self.isSubscribing()):
            self.peripheralState = socket.recv_pyobj()
            #print( type(self.peripheralState))
            #print( self.peripheralState )
            periDict = self.peripheralState["p2"]
            index = 1
            for key in periDict:
                #print("key: %s , value: %s" % (key, periDict[key]))
                if(index == 1 and self.isSubscribing()):
                    key1.append( periDict[key] )
                    if( len(key1) > PLOT_MAX):
                        key1.pop(0)
                if(index == 2 and self.isSubscribing() ):
                    key2.append( periDict[key] )
                    if( len(key2) > PLOT_MAX):
                        key2.pop(0)
                if(index == 3 and self.isSubscribing()):
                    key3.append( periDict[key] )
                    if( len(key3) > PLOT_MAX):
                        key3.pop(0)

                index = index + 1


        print('refreshState is terminated!')

def updateStreamingUi(i):
    plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
    axs[0].clear()
    axs[0].set_ylim(min(key1), max(key1))
    axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
    axs[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
    x1 = np.arange(-1,len(key1)-1,1)
    axs[0].fill_between(x1,min(key1),key1,color=PLOT_FILL_COLOR)

    axs[1].clear()
    axs[1].set_ylim(min(key2), max(key2))
    axs[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
    axs[1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
    x2 = np.arange(-1,len(key2)-1,1)
    axs[1].fill_between(x2,min(key2),key2,color=PLOT_FILL_COLOR)

    axs[2].clear()
    axs[2].set_ylim(min(key3), max(key3))
    axs[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
    axs[2].xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
    x3 = np.arange(-1,len(key3)-1,1)
    axs[2].fill_between(x3,min(key3),key3,color=PLOT_FILL_COLOR)

def refreshStateMain(port, app):
    print('getting message...')
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB) # pylint: disable=no-member
    subUrl = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:' + str(port)
    socket.connect(subUrl)
    try:
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') # pylint: disable=no-member
    except TypeError:
        socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') # pylint: disable=no-member
    print('refreshState isSubscribing='+str(app.isSubscribing()))
    while(app.isSubscribing()):
        app.peripheralState = socket.recv_pyobj()
        print( type(app.peripheralState))
        print( app.peripheralState )
        # get p1 for example
        periDict = app.peripheralState["p2"]
        index = 1
        for key in periDict:
            print("key: %s , value: %s" % (key, periDict[key]))

            if(index == 1 and app.isSubscribing()):
                key1.append( periDict[key] )
            if( len(key1) > PLOT_MAX):
                key1.pop(0)
            if(index == 2 and app.isSubscribing() ):
                key2.append( periDict[key] )
            if( len(key2) > PLOT_MAX):
                key2.pop(0)
            if(index == 3 and app.isSubscribing()):
                key3.append( periDict[key] )
            if( len(key3) > PLOT_MAX):
                key3.pop(0)

            index = index + 1

        print('refreshState isSubscribing='+str(app.isSubscribing()))
 
        print('refreshState is terminated!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)
    plt.ion()
    plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, rowspan=4,
        sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateStreamingUi, interval=1000, blit=False)
    app = SIControllerUI(master=root)
    app.startup()
    app.mainloop()
```

Thank you

Comment: I think the block occurs while the plot is redrawn which takes a long time because you delete everything to redraw. Maybe you can try to find a way to just edit some of the points of the plot.